# Having trouble with custom date field for CPT query (Wordpress)

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-field, query

I've read as many of the questions and answers on here as I can find and none of the solutions are working for me. No idea what I'm doing wrong here.

I have a CPT 'event' with meta key 'start_date' - This saves to DB in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format exactly the same as the standard post_date format.

Yet I have a query which is not sorting these posts by the meta key but by the post_date no matter what I try.

I've got the actual CPT archive sorting correctly by start_date, but the query I'm using elsewhere (on homepage section) just will not work.

Here's my query:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'event',
    'posts_per_page' => 2,
    'order_by' => 'meta_value',
    'meta_key' => 'start_date'
) );
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
```

I've tried so many variations and yet it still just displays the posts by post_date rather than start_date.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing it's because you used `order_by` when it should actually be `orderby` - that `order_by` wasn't just a typo in the question, right?

And also, if the meta value is a date, then you should also set the `meta_type` parameter to `DATE` so that the sorting works as expected.

So try with:

```php
$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type'      => 'event',
    'posts_per_page' => 2,
    'orderby'        => 'meta_value', // it's orderby; not order_by
    'meta_key'       => 'start_date',
    'meta_type'      => 'DATE',       // and set meta_type to DATE
) );
```

### Update

If the above still doesn't work, try using `meta_query` instead of those `meta_key` and `meta_type`, and set the `orderby` to `start_date` - the key in the `meta_query` for the metadata `start_date`:

```php
$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type'      => 'event',
    'posts_per_page' => 2,
    'meta_query'     => array(
        'start_date' => array(
            'key'  => 'start_date',
            'type' => 'DATE',
        ),
    ),
    'orderby'        => 'start_date',
) );
```

However, if there's a plugin or custom code overriding the `orderby`, e.g. via `pre_get_posts`, then I doubt the above would work.

But you can try it, who knows it magically works... also, try clearing your site caches - just in case.

Comment: Thanks Sally, I did indeed have that typo but it's actually still not working even with orderby and the code you kindly provided :( Still just going by post_date...

Comment: In that case, then with the above code, what's the output of `echo $the_query->request;` ? Perhaps a plugin is filtering the query. And are you actually sure the sorting is indeed by the *post* date?

Comment: Here's the output: SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS tmrlg_posts.ID FROM tmrlg_posts INNER JOIN tmrlg_postmeta ON ( tmrlg_posts.ID = tmrlg_postmeta.post_id ) WHERE 1=1 AND ( tmrlg_postmeta.meta_key = 'start_date' ) AND tmrlg_posts.post_type = 'event' AND (tmrlg_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR tmrlg_posts.post_status = 'private') GROUP BY tmrlg_posts.ID ORDER BY tmrlg_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 2

Comment: Try adding `'suppress_filters' => true,` to your query args and see if the issue persists.

Comment: But that isn't a solution - it's just to confirm a plugin or custom code is overriding the sorting.

Comment: Thanks Sally. Adding suppress_filters here's the output (no change from what I can see): SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS tmrlg_posts.ID FROM tmrlg_posts INNER JOIN tmrlg_postmeta ON ( tmrlg_posts.ID = tmrlg_postmeta.post_id ) WHERE 1=1 AND ( tmrlg_postmeta.meta_key = 'start_date' ) AND tmrlg_posts.post_type = 'event' AND (tmrlg_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR tmrlg_posts.post_status = 'private') GROUP BY tmrlg_posts.ID ORDER BY tmrlg_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 2

Comment: Thanks for the updated code! It's still not made any difference D; Output is still the same. What a nightmare. I do have a pre_get_posts in functions for the event post type archive, but disabling that doesn't make any difference either...

Comment: Well then, I guess you'll have to try deactivating all plugins and see if the issue still persists - if not, then you know what to do (or what's happening..). You can also try the code with the default theme (e.g. Twenty Twenty).. via a child theme or plugin you put in the `wp-content/mu-plugins` directory.

Comment: I'll have a play around with plugins. Thanks so much for your help regardless!

Comment: No problem. And if the sorting just won't work even after doing all that I've just said, then there's one more code (using a hook) you can try, but let's talk about it again once you're done with the plugins and theme - i.e. let us know your findings! :)

Comment: Alright I'm out of ideas again. Tried on default theme + no plugins and getting the same issue.

Comment: Are you sure this is not a server/browser caching issue? But before trying [another code](https://gist.github.com/5ally/92bec0b1d718046016b9dbb0ce4d6c6d), you can try reinstalling the WordPress core files via the Dashboard -> Updates admin page, and see if that helps. If not, try that another code. If that also doesn't help, then I think you should hire someone to professionally check the issue for you..

Comment: Hi Sally, thanks again for all your help with this. Unfortunately reinstalling the core files didn't work and that other code you suggested also didn't have any effect, so looks like I'll be getting some professional help with this one.

Comment: Well I hope the issue will be, if not already, solved ASAP.. and if possible, please share (by writing your own answer) the solution you ended up using - or let us know what exactly happened and how did you solve it. +1 to the question, BTW. :)

Comment: Turns out I did indeed have an existing pre_get_posts in use for a 'sorting options bar' I'd added - Removing that solved the issue.

Comment: Hey @LornWaterfield, thank you for letting me know and also for accepting my answer. :) Cheers!